# PHP array merge with different type of keys

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii2

Is there any way to merge the array key with unique name, so i can get the unique key with their types and values. I am using yii2 and mysql

I am using the following SQL Query in yii2:

```
$data= $query->SELECT(["sum(no_of_pages) as pages_coded",'assigned_to','type_of_request','concat(firstname," ",lastname) as userfullname'])
->from('task')
->leftJoin('user','user.username = task.assigned_to')
->andWhere("sdlc_phase='Resolved'")
->orWhere("sdlc_phase='Semi_Resolved'");
$query->groupby(['assigned_to', 'type_of_request']);
//$query->->addGroupBy('assigned_to');
$query->orderby(['assigned_to'=>SORT_ASC]);
$data = $query->all();
```

and Output of SQL Query is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [pages_coded] => 5
            [type_of_request] => Collector Tweak
            [userfullname] => Sam
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [pages_coded] => 5
            [type_of_request] => Collector Code
            [userfullname] => John
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [pages_coded] => 42
            [type_of_request] => Collector Tweak
            [userfullname] => John
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [pages_coded] => 37
            [type_of_request] => Clinical Tweak
            [userfullname] => Dona
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [pages_coded] => 35
            [type_of_request] => Collector Code
            [userfullname] => Dona
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [pages_coded] => 7
            [type_of_request] => Clinical Code
            [userfullname] => Ricky
        )
    [6] => Array
        (
            [pages_coded] => 50
            [type_of_request] => Clinical Tweak
            [userfullname] => Ricky
        )
    [7] => Array
        (
            [pages_coded] => 4
            [type_of_request] => Collector Code
            [userfullname] => Ricky
        )
    [8] => Array
        (
            [pages_coded] => 17
            [type_of_request] => Collector Tweak
            [userfullname] => Ricky
        )
)
```

However I want the generate the output like this, is there anyway to get this

```
 Array
(
    [Sam] => Array
        (
            [0] => Clinical Code
            [1] => 0
            [2] => Clinical Tweak
            [3] => 0
            [4] => Collector Code
            [5] => 0
            [6] => Collector Tweak
            [7] => 5
        )
    [John] => Array
        (
            [0] => Clinical Code
            [1] => 0
            [2] => Clinical Tweak
            [3] => 0
            [4] => Collector Code
            [5] => 5
            [6] => Collector Tweak
            [7] => 42
        )
    [Dona] => Array
        (
            [0] => Clinical Code
            [1] => 0
            [2] => Clinical Tweak
            [3] => 37
            [4] => Collector Code
            [5] => 0
            [6] => Collector Tweak
            [7] => 35
        )
   [Ricky] => Array
        (
            [0] => Clinical Code
            [1] => 7
            [2] => Clinical Tweak
            [3] => 50
            [4] => Collector Code
            [5] => 4
            [6] => Collector Tweak
            [7] => 17
        )
)
```

help me sort out this issue.

Comment: Yes - you can use foreach and build array in format what you want.

Comment: From the database, no, from PHP, yes. But the notation you are using for the arrays would be better in a different way.

Comment: I must say that expected output looks hard to use. Why not make the array associative and use (example) 'Clinical Code' as the key with a value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the output you want you will have to loop through the results creating another array.

```
$output = array();
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $output[$row['userfullname']][$row['type_of_request']] = $row['pages_coded'];
}
```

Like this you will end up with arrays like:

```
$output = array(
    'Sam' => array(
        'Collector Tweak' => 5
    ),
);
```

And since you apparently want the other columns filled by 0 if they couldn't be found:

```
$categories = array(
    'Clinical Code' => 0,
    'Clinical Tweak' => 0,
    'Collector Code' => 0,
    'Collector Tweak' => 0,
);
foreach ($output as &$outputItem) {
    $outputItem = array_merge($categories, $outputItem);
}
```

Which is, by definition, easier to track indexes and their respective values.

Tested here: https://3v4l.org/0k40Q

Comment: Instead of the second loop (nested foreach) you can probably use array_diff some how to find what array items is missing and add them that way

Comment: Not a bad idea, let me test it somewhere. @Andreas, you got the right idea with the wrong function, I think. `array_merge()` is the one that does the trick.

Comment: Good one! I was thinking of arrsy_diff_key. It should (I think) also work. Any subarray that does not have all four, array diff will indeed them and append. But I haven't tested it

Comment: `array_diff()` would promptly show the difference and `array_diff_key()` is the same case, by any means they would have to be appended later to the original array, but the suggestion to use an array function for it was great anyway, thank you.

Comment: Hi @Rafael, $output array is printing fine but $outputItem is printing only one value,is not merged with $output array. below is output                                  Array
(
    [Clinical Code] => 0
    [Clinical Tweak] => 7
    [Collector Code] => 0
    [Collector Tweak] => 0
)

Comment: Well, `$outputItem` is just one item out of all the items in the array `$output`, therefore it will print only one value. But it is being updated back to the `$output` array using reference **&** as you can see in the `foreach()` line. I'm gonna add a snippet to this. You should be able to see it in a few minutes in the bottom of the answer.

Comment: Updated with the link. Do you know how references work?

Comment: So, please upvote the answer and check it as the answer to close the question. :) Good luck.